# Next and previous actions not working with MediaButtonReceiver

Tags: android, android-mediasession

I have a music streaming service which uses the `onStartCommand` method and performs a handleIntent. What I want to achieve is that if I connect my device to a bluetooth device like a speaker, I can skip songs from the speaker but it is not working. What does work is pausing and resuming songs from the physical buttons on the speaker.

My Manifest:

```
 <receiver android:name="androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Service:

```
 private var mediaSessionCompat: MediaSessionCompat ? = null

 override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent ? , flags : Int, startId: Int): Int {
   if (mediaSessionCompat == null) {
     mediaSessionCompat = MediaSessionCompat(applicationContext, "MyMediaSessionCompat")
   }
   MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent(mediaSessionCompat, intent)
   handleIntent(intent)
   return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
 }
```